# CheckMarx FLS Security Issue

Tags: salesforce1-app, checkmarx

I have applied updatable check still checkmarx report showing issues,Any idea..
Code:

```
Account Ac=new Account();
Ac.level_of_care__c='hhs';

if(Schema.sobjecttype.Account.isUpdateable() && Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.level_of_care__c.isUpdateable()){
    update Ac;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the setting of the field on your in-memory Account record into the if statement, so that the check is done before you attempt to assign?

Comment: Just an idea -you createing new account, so possible the scanner expect you to check IsCreatable properties on the object/field.... By the way, I think it will fail in SF run time as you trying to update record without Id